# Winston logging file name to a transport

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I have the following logger module:

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, label, printf, colorize } = format;
const logger = require('winston');
const { red } = require('colors')
const myFormat = printf(info => {
    return `${info.timestamp} [${info.label}] ${info.level}: 
      ${info.message}`;
      });

module.exports = logger.createLogger({
level: 'silly',
format: combine(
    label({ label: 'mylogger1' }),
    timestamp(),
    myFormat,
    //logger.format.json(),
  ),
transports: [
  new logger.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
  new logger.transports.Console({
    format: combine(
        myFormat
     )}
   )
 ]
});
```

Then i use it in another file like this:

```
const myLogger = require('./loggermodule');

myLogger.log("verbose","an error occurred in this file: " + 
  module.filename);
```

As you can see I am using module.filename to logging the name of the file where the log is happening.

I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve the same result

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when an error is thrown, the filename is specified in the stack trace:

```
try {

} catch (e) {
    logger.error(e.stack); // log stack
}
```

But if you need to specify the filename yourself, you can create a wrapper function like:

```
/// const winston = require('winston');
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    // ...
});

logger.prototype.logFilename = function (level, filename, message = "") {
    logger.log(level, "An error occurred in this file", filename, message);
}

module.exports = logger;
```

Then:

```
const myLogger = require('./loggermodule');

myLogger.logFilename("verbose", module.filename);
```